# Comparing two data columns in two different worksheets and printing the difference/mismatch in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare two data columns together in two different worksheets and get the differences/mismatches to copy onto a third worksheet. When I run this code down below, it says there are no mismatches, which is false because there are. Would people recommend a vlookup, multidimensional for loop, match,etc?

```
'Project title variables
Dim currentTitle As String, oldTitle As String

'Use a variable to store the current row we are writing to
Dim rowRep As Long, rowData As Long
rowRep = ROW_REP_START
rowData = 1


'Go through each row
Dim rgCurRow As Range, rng As Range
For Each rgCurRow In rgCurrentData.Rows

    currentTitle = rgCurRow.Cells(1, COL_CURRENTDATA_PROJECTTITLE)


    oldTitle = rgCurRow.Cells(1, COL_OLDDATA_PROJECTTITLE)

    If Not StrComp(currentTitle, oldTitle, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

        'Get the destination range - where the data will be written
         shResultSheet.Cells(rowRep, COL_REP_OWNINGBUSINESS).Value2 = rgCurrentData.Cells(rowData, COL_CURRENTDATA_OWNINGBUSINESS).Value2
         shResultSheet.Cells(rowRep, COL_REP_BUSINESSSPONSOR).Value2 = rgCurrentData.Cells(rowData, COL_CURRENTDATA_BUSINESSSPONSOR).Value2
         shResultSheet.Cells(rowRep, COL_REP_TECHLEAD).Value2 = rgCurrentData.Cells(rowData, COL_CURRENTDATA_TECHLEAD).Value2
         shResultSheet.Cells(rowRep, COL_REP_TITLE).Value2 = rgCurrentData.Cells(rowData, COL_CURRENTDATA_PROJECTTITLE).Value2
         shResultSheet.Cells(rowRep, COL_REP_DESCRIPTION).Value2 = rgCurrentData.Cells(rowData, COL_CURRENTDATA_DESCRIPTION).Value2
         shResultSheet.Cells(rowRep, COL_REP_CURRENTSTATE).Value2 = rgCurrentData.Cells(rowData, COL_CURRENTDATA_CURRENTSTATE).Value2
         shResultSheet.Cells(rowRep, COL_REP_CURRENTSTATUS).Value2 = rgCurrentData.Cells(rowData, COL_CURRENTDATA_CURRENTSTATUS).Value2

    End If

    'Move to the next report row
    rowRep = rowRep + 1
    rowData = rowData + 1

Next rgCurRow
```

Comment: Please include the problem you are having, such as the error codes or the incorrect end result.

Comment: thanks for the comment...i made some edit and additions to the question

Comment: You say that the data is on two separate worksheets, but in the code above it looks like it is only in two columns on the same sheet. Is that intentional? Also it appears that the mismatches are going to be placed on the same row as the actual mismatch. Which means if you have the first mismatch on row 1000, on the result sheet the row 1000 will be the first piece of data you have. Is that intentional?

Comment: So nothing is really intentional because I am new to coding. I did not know how to give the "oldTitle" a different range, so i left it as is with "rgCurRow". If you have fixes, please go ahead  and fix them at will

Comment: I can't understand this code. Let's break it down. Supposing you have SheetA and SheetB. Are you comparing each element on column A on SheetA to the corresponding row in column B on SheetB? If so, are you pasting the value of ColumnA or Column B to the new Worksheet? Can you also paste links to pictures showing your sheets, and the results you would like to have?

Comment: Does order matter? Is it requiring only that the list of old titles CONTAINS each of the new titles, or do you need old title number 5 to be the same as new title number 5?